# Run command from Jenkins to Linux Server

Tags: jenkins, linux

I have a HAProxy server setup in Azure Linux Machine. How can I run a HAProxy start/stop command from Jenkins to multiple Linux server?

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access from the Jenkins machine to the HAProxy machine, you could run an Ansible task:

`ansible -i ha-inventory.ini ha-servers -m service -a name=haproxy state=restarted`

Of course you could also have Jenkins do a simple ssh :

`for server in ${server_list} ; do ssh server 'sudo service haproxy restart' ; done`

For both of these, you would need

- ssh keys set up between Jenkins and the HAProxy servers
- sudo rights for restarting the service (at least) for the connecting user (probably `jenkins`)